# QTreeView function rootIsDecorated not working

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview

I am new to QT but trying to change a tree model so that it initiates with a drop down when the window is loaded. So I want to change it from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

This is my code: I would also like to change the size without setting fixed, min or max but resize and setGeometry are not working! Please help

```
    self.tree_model = QComponentTreeModel(self.model)
    self.tree_view = QComponentTreeView()
    self.tree_view.setRootIsDecorated(False)
    self.tree_view.setModel(self.tree_model)
    self.tree_view.show()
    self.tree_view.clicked.connect(self.componentSelected)
    self.currentComponentChanged.connect(
        self.tree_view.currentComponentChanged)
    self.tree_view.setMinimumWidth(400)
    self.tree_view.setMinimumHeight(300)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear.

From the title ("QTreeView function rootIsDecorated not working") it seems that what you want is to hide the controls to expand/collapse child items for `ROOT` as well as all the model items under it. You expect `rootIsDecorated` property to take care of this and it doesn't work the way you expect. However, as far as I can see, `rootIsDecorated` property works exactly the way it is [documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#rootIsDecorated-prop) to work:

> This property holds whether to show controls for expanding and collapsing **top-level items**
>
> Items with children are typically shown with controls to expand and collapse them, allowing their children to be shown or hidden. If this property is false, these controls are not shown **for top-level items**. This can be used to make a single level tree structure appear like a simple list of items.

The only top-level item in your example is `ROOT`. There is no control to expand/collapse its children - that's `rootIsDecorated` property working as it is intended to work. It is not intended to do anything about controls for non-top level items i.e. children of `ROOT` in your example.

A completely different question pops up from the first sentence in the question description:

> trying to change a tree model so that it initiates with a drop down when the window is loaded

So probably you want the `ROOT` item expanded as soon as the view with model connected to it is displayed? That's a completely different thing from what `rootIsDecorated` property is about. What you need to do for the item to become expanded is to call [expand](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#expand) method of `QTreeView` with the appropriate model index. For example, let's suppose that your model has `rootItemIndex` method which returns `QModelIndex` corresponding to the item called `ROOT`. Then you need to do the following in your code to make that item expanded:

```
self.tree_view.setModel(self.tree_model)
self.tree_view.expand(self.tree_model.rootItemIndex())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. You're right I was really looking to solve the second problem. That has worked now :) .